# How to sort by eager loading results in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am extremely new to eager loading and have run into what I assume to be a simple problem of me just not understanding it. I reviewed some of [the materials here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) and have looked around but can't seem to get maybe the right terminology for what I am asking.

At the moment in my equipment model I have the following relationship:

```
public function registrationsExpireLatest()
{
       return $this->hasOne(EquipmentLicense::class,'equipmentID','id')
    ->orderByDesc('expirationDate');
}
```

This works perfectly, but say I want to put it on an index blade under an @foreach, I get everything I need, including the expiration date using the code below:

```
        @foreach ($equipments as $equipment)

             <tr>
                 <td><a href="/origins/{{$equipment['id']}}">{{$equipment['unit_id']}}</a></td>
                 <td>{{\Crypt::decryptString($equipment->licensePlate)}}</td>
                 <td>@if (count($equipment->registrationsExpireLatest))
                     {{$equipment->registrationsExpireLatest->expirationDate}}
                    @endif</td>
            </tr>

        @endforeach
```

Coming from this controller code:

```
    $equipments = Equipment::with(['registrationsExpireLatest' => function ($query) {
                                    $query->orderBy('expirationDate', 'asc');
                                }])
                                ->where([
                                    ['unit_type','<',3],
                                    ['active','=',1]
                                    ])
                                ->limit(10)
                                ->get();
```

Which all outputs like this:

```
11      086-YRR     2015-05-31
26      062-XWE     2018-11-30
33      880-HNV     2018-04-30
39      820-YYT     2018-01-31
203     279-WWU     2013-12-31
31      BMR 199     2018-04-30
UNK3    997-WLH     2011-09-30
1       957-VDN     2018-05-31
1096    187-MFF     2015-01-31
2105    154-CLU     2018-01-31
```

As you can see by my controller, I tried sorting already in what I thought was the proper way put out here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

But as you can see from my results table, they are out of order according to the expiration date.

I'd like it to go earlier (as in 2011) to later (as in 2018) by date. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: This is a different thing. If you search for 'laravel orderby on relationship' you will find out your solution.

Comment: @Spacemudd - Do you have an example? I looked through some and they all seem to want me to use join, but I am not sure how to limit that to one equipment item (which in reality can have a few dozen EquipmentLicense in the database. If I go the way they are suggesting, multiple equipment records now appear (say for 11 in the table above, only was getting 1 (the latest) because of the relationship, but now it has 9, including the latest and all of the earlier registrations as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(based on [Namoshek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49562966/4848587))*

The JOIN requires an alias:

```
Equipment::where([
        ['unit_type','<',3],
        ['active','=',1]
    ])
    ->join(DB::raw('(SELECT equipmentID, MAX(expirationDate) AS latest FROM equipment_license GROUP BY equipmentID) as license'), 'equipment.id', '=', 'license.equipmentID')
    ->orderBy('license.latest')
    ->limit(10)
    ->get();
```

Comment: By the end of this I think I'm going to be owing you a lot of thanks. Thank you so much for all of the help! I'm extremely appreciative!

Answer (score 2):

What you are currently doing is sorting the related collection, i.e. if `registrationsExpireLatest` was a one-to-many relation, the related models would have been sorted in ascending order by their `expirationDate` for each of your `Equipments`. As far as I can see from your model, you already join the latest entity anyway.

To sort the `Equipments` on a relation is normally not that hard, you just have to join the related table. But in your case, where you have multiple elements in the related table per `Equipment`, the join is a bit more complex. I think something like the following could work:

```
Equipment::where([
        ['unit_type','<',3],
        ['active','=',1]
    ])
    ->join(DB::raw('(SELECT equipmentID, MAX(expirationDate) AS latest FROM equipment_license GROUP BY equipmentID) AS tmp'), 'equipment.id', '=', 'tmp.equipmentID')
    ->orderBy('tmp.latest')
    ->select('equipment.*', 'tmp.latest')
    ->limit(10)
    ->get();
```

Comment: I have made your suggestion, but I run into this issue: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT equipmentID, MAX(expirationDate) AS latest FROM equipment_licenses GROUP ' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `equipment` inner join SELECT equipmentID, MAX(expirationDate) AS latest FROM equipment_licenses GROUP BY equipmentID on `equipment`.`id` = `equipment_licenses`.`equipmentID` where (`unit_type` < 3 and `active` = 1)

Comment: order by `equipment_licenses`.`latest` asc limit 10)

Comment: I wasn't sure about the `equipment_license` table name because on the model is mentioned in your question - is that one correct? Have you checked it?

Comment: I made a few changes (all had to be changed to equipment_licenses, rather than singular. But when I ran it through mysql, everything is fine until I reach the orderBy section and it says column unknown: 'equipment_license.latest'

Comment: Try `ORDER BY latest` without the `equipment_licenses.`. Another solution would be a wrapping `SELECT` query around it, but I doubt this is necessary...

Comment: Well that worked on going through mysql, but I'm still running into issues with laravel, pretty much the same error as above. I'll try what you suggested about the select.

Comment: Out of curiosity, would you have a specific place to put the ORDER BY latest section? Nothing's changed and I think I've tried nearly every combination...

Comment: No, it shouldn't matter where you put the individual method calls in the query building process, as long as you do it before the `->get()` call and not in a nested function. In the background Laravel just collects your query requirements and only when you call `->get()`, the query is built. But to get back to your problem, I edited my answer above with a query that I have tested locally and that worked fine with SQL Server (which is normally more picky than MySQL, so you should be fine). Major change is the sub query in the join.